# Tapestry or JSP - OR condition

Tags: java, jsp, tapestry

I am new to [Tapestry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tapestry) and [JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Server_Pages). How can I write this directive?

If jwcid is either **isNotFSC** OR **isFSCIP**, then it needs to display that field.

```html
<tr>
    <td class="field-label">Created: </td>
    <td><text jwcid="created">00/00/0000</text></td>
    <td class="field-label">Created By: </td>
    <td><text jwcid="createdBy">Claims project</text> </td>

    <if jwcid = "isNotFSC" || jwcid = "isFSCIP">
        <td><submit id="startFollowupARequirementTask" jwcid="startFollowupARequirementTask"/></td>
    </if>
</tr>
```

How is the OR condition is written in Tapestry or JSP?

Comment: The code looks very old indeed. Please clarify the Tapestry version?